# Read table without blank rows to Insert to other table using vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am Using Access VBA to read from a temp table and then inserting those values to another table, But i am getting blank rows while Inserting.
I need a way to remove the blank rows.

```
  Table A        Table B
  A B C D         ID B
  1 1 1 1         1  1
  1 1   1         2  1
  1     1         3

**Expected Result**
    Table B
     ID  B
     1   1
     2   1
```

i am Inserting column B from Table A to Table B but i am getting one blank row which is not required

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_B(B) SELECT B FROM TABLE_A WHERE B is not null;"
```

Comment: Does that third "blank" row in table A really have a null B value, or could it be empty string?

Comment: i tried this sql code too but getting same result INSERT INTO TABLE_B(B) SELECT B FROM TABLE_A WHERE B is not null AND B <> ' ';

Comment: @polycarp you could not have got the same result, since there cannot be any records that satisfy the where criteria.

Comment: i am getting Temp table Table_A from excel sheet using vba  DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet, so i think the blank will be null

Comment: Your SQL syntax works for me but deal with the possibility of either Null or empty string: `INSERT INTO TABLE_B(B) SELECT B FROM TABLE_A WHERE B & "" <> ""`

Answer (score 0):

Specify criteria that excludes *both* **[Null values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character)** *and* **[Zero-Length Strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_string)**:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_B(B) SELECT B FROM TABLE_A WHERE B Is Not Null AND B <>'';
```

---

### More info :

- [NULL v. Zero Length String](http://www.599cd.com/tips/access/null-zls/)